# multiple file upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying multiple file upload in Codeigniter.I uses following code for this

```
$count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    for($s=1; $s<=$count; $s++) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']=$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']=  $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$s];
            $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
            $this->upload->do_upload();
    }
    private function set_upload_options(){
                         $config = array();
                        $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
                        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                        $config['max_size'] = '100';
                        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                        $config['max_height']  = '768';
                        return $config;
                        }
```

I am getting only first file in array uploaded..rest of files in array are not uploaded...is there anything wrong in this code...i cant figure it out...please help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here. First :

`$_FILES['userfile']['size']` will return the volume of the files in bytes... As it is an integer, the `count` function will return `1` every time. Use the array `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` instead :

```
$count = count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
```

Then, you are overwriting the `$_FILES` superglobal. So you will have to use a local variable to save it :

```
$count = count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
$files = $_FILES;
for($s=1; $s<=$count; $s++) {
    $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$s];
    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
    $this->upload->do_upload();
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay...but it doesn't works..still only first file uploads.when i debug i found that $_FILES['userfile'][' '] is not assigning value after first iteration..what is the reson for it?? any idea or suggestion will be very helpful for me

Comment: @sarincm99 Ho yes, sorry I didn't notice the second problem here. Check my edit

Comment: @Brewal..thanks a lot..it works..a simple fix..but cant figure it out..you saved me...Thanks again brewal

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your controller inside method.

$image_path = $this->input->post('userfile');

```
      $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);   //If file choosen to upload then ex
     // print_r($_FILES); die();
        $files = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $type  = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
        $tmp_name  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $error = $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
        $size = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
       //print_r($files); die();
   // print_r($_FILES['userfile']['name']); die();
      for ($i=0; $i <$count ; $i++) 
          # code...
                      {

                //File Upload Configuration.
                $config['upload_path'] = 'new/';
                //echo $config['upload_path'].'<br>';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|JPG|PNG|GIF';
                $config['max_size'] = '3048';
                $config['overwrite'] = false;
                $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
                $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
                $image_path_name = 'userfile';



                 $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$files[$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $type[$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $tmp_name[$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $error[$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $size[$i]; 
                $this->load->library('upload', $config); //Load library
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($image_path_name))
                {
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('file','File not uploaded');
                   redirect('front/prop_sale');
                }
                else
                {
                    // File uploaded successfully


                    $image_path[$i] = base_url().'new/'.$this->upload->file_name;

                    //print_r($image_path);
                }
            }
```