# Multiple file upload in codeigniter: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_escapeshellarg() (previously declared in ...\system\libraries\Upload.php:1038)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I tried to upload 2 types of files, image and pdf in different location. But i am getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_escapeshellarg() (previously declared in ...\system\libraries\Upload.php:1038).

**Here is my controller:**

```
$config['upload_path']   = './uploads/category_imgs/';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){   

    $imgname ='noimage.png';

    $image_thumb ='noimage_thumb.png';

} else {

    $data = $this->upload->data(); 

    $imgname = $data['file_name'];

    $path_parts = pathinfo($imgname);

    //$image_path = $path_parts['filename'].'._.'.date("Y-m-d h:i:s").'.'.$path_parts['extension'];

}

$filepath = '';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/category_brochure/';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('brochure')) {

    $data['uploaderror'] = array('error' =>      $this->upload->display_errors());

} else {

    $arrUploadFileDetails = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    $filepath = $arrUploadFileDetails['upload_data']['file_name'];

    $filExtension = $arrUploadFileDetails['upload_data']['file_ext'];
}
```

**Can anyone  point out my mistake**

Comment: The error message says what is your problem.You included this `my_escapeshellarg` function twice

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841344/multiple-file-upload-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You've got the following line in there twice:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

This is then trying to load the library twice, and causing the issue you are having.  If you need to change the config for the uploads, then you should use:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

when you set the config for the second upload.

Comment: I removed the second $this->load->library and initialized the $config. But still the same error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two

`<input type="file" name="userfile" multiple="multiple">`

And

`<input type="file" name="brochure" multiple="multiple">`

**On the same view page**

You could use this do upload function below I use this code with codeigniter form validation callback for multiple file uploads on one page.

```
public function do_upload() {

    foreach ($_FILES as $field_name => $value) {

        if ($value['name'] != '') {

            $this->load->library('upload');

            $this->upload->initialize($this->do_upload_options());

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {

                $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());

                return FALSE;

            } else {

                return TRUE;
            }

        }
    }

}

public function do_upload_options() {
    $config = array();

    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png|jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '30000';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';

    return $config;
}
```